# How come in chrome I get a black background when trying to print but in IE it looks fine

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, printing-web-page

Does anyone know why I maybe getting black backgrounds in my article tags when I go to print my web page.  The backgrounds are actually white and in internet explorer they look just fine.  It displays a black background in the chrome print preview and prints with it being black where Internet explorer does not.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide any information.  What's your CSS look like?  Can you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by the DIV attributes. If you remove either the round corner or the shadow specs, it is back to normal. The pdf.dll plugin might not support the round corner DIV with shadow.

It seems like the issue has been removed due to its not a priority. Check your version of chrome or try to modify div class dinamically just when going to print.

[Issue details](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=342204)

Answer (score 1):

I was actually able to solve it by specifying in the css that the background is white.  Apparently in Chrome if you don't say,  it will print in black but display in white..  Thanks though.